# Embedded DocuSign signing: session timeout page

Tags: docusignapi

In DocuSign embedded signing with php, before finish if session timeout, error alert is displaying repeatedly (bad request response from demo.docusign monitoring session link) and when we click ok, it is taking to session timeout page. How can I stop displaying alert repeatedly and how to customise session timeout page? how to get the finish button click event in our application?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to change the wording on the session timeout page via the branding feature. [Docs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-advanced-branding-configuration)

You may also be able to detect timeouts from your application by using the [ping feature](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/#schema__recipientviewrequest_pingurl) of embedded signing. If the ping stops then the embedded signing session has ended.

Lastly, you can make your application more flexible: if your app does not receive the redirect from the signing session then you know that the signing session did not complete normally. Then, you can send email to the signer (if appropriate), or wait until the next time they use your application.